# Удалить елемент из массива

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста есть массив объектов

Как удалить объект по id ? к примеру удалить с id 201 ?

```
[
  {
    "id": 200,
    "name": "Первый",
  },
  {
    "id": 201,
    "name": "Второй",
  },
  {
    "id": 202,
    "name": "Третий",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = items.filter(item => item.id != 201);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]